# Bridging wlan0 and eth0 with pi 3 on Raspbian Jessie

Tags: raspbian, networking, pi-3

I am trying to bridge wlan0 and eth0 on my pi 3 running the latest Raspbian "Jessie".

I am running into 2 issues when trying to set this up.

1. when trying to use command `sudo brctl addif bro wlan0 eth0`, I get `can't add wlan0 to bridge br0: operation not supported`
2. I can't get to the bridge to automatically setup on reboot.  Should I be working in the `/etc/network/interfaces` or `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`?

I what I trying to do it share the wlan0 connection over eth0 on my pi3 to a second pi device.  I am currently connecting to the pi3 through ssh over the wifi connection.

Comment: Another one http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51057/raspberry-pi-3-model-b-wireless-bridge-to-ethernet