# Raspberry PI 3 MODEL B - Wireless Bridge to ethernet

Tags: wifi, pi-3, ethernet

I've seen a lot online for a solution to make raspberry Pi 3 into a wireless bridge. But many are old articles to suit the Pi 1 and 2.

This is the last article I have seen, and tried: 
http://blog.slor.net/2013/09/turning-your-raspberri-pi-into-wireless.html

I use RASPBIAN JESSIE, Kernel version: 4.4.

I want the Pi to connect to a wireless router with the built-in wireless device (wlan0) to provide access to device(s)that are connected to the built-in Ethernet connector (eth0).

I want the router (192.168.1.1) to provide IP's to devices connected to RPi3, making it possible for the PC to communicate with devices connected to RPi3.

The problem is when I try to follow the article linked above is that when I run this command:

```
sudo brctl addif br0 wlan0 eth0
```

I get this error message:

```
can't add wlan0 to bridge br0: Operation not supported...
```

[image]

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this?

[image]

Comment: Have you created `br0` before that? `brctl addbr br0`.

Comment: Yes I've tried that, but get still the error message:

can't add wlan0 to bridge br0: Operation not supported

Comment: Do other commands work like `brctl show`? Maybe a.module is missing.

Comment: Screenshot here: [link](http://i.imgur.com/jqUHnVD.png)

Comment: Ok, I think you can add only one interface with each command. You have to serialize it. `brctl addif br0 wlan0` and then `brctl addif br0 eth0`,

Comment: With the first command `brctl addif br0 wlan0` i still get: "can't add wlan0 to bridge br0: Operation not supported". But the last command `brctl addif br0 eth0` works.

Comment: Ok, learning something new every day. Bridging wireless isn't possible (yet) it seems: http://serverfault.com/questions/152363/bridging-wlan0-to-eth0

Comment: hmm Strange ... it seems to work on older models (according to the article), but not the new RPi3.

Comment: @ott That post and the LKM thread it links to **are 6+ years old**, so anyone seriously interested in the issue may want to dig a little bit further.   [This answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/151200/25985) implies it may be simpler to just forward and masquerade rather than trying to use a legit [layer 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_link_layer) bridge.

Comment: @3kbest does a `iw dev wlan0 set 4addr on` before `brctl addif br0 wlan0 eth0` help? for my pi2 I had this setting in /etc/network/interfaces but it should be the same for the pi3:
`auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet manual
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
      bridge_ports wlan0 eth0
      bridge_stp off
      bridge_maxwait 5
wpa-iface wlan0
wpa-bridge br0
wpa-driver wext
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` hope it is still readable due missing linebreaks, google this and you will find a formated interfaces snipplet

Comment: Just seen this link below. Yet to try. Wanna give it a go?. https://rbnrpi.wordpress.com/project-list/wifi-to-ethernet-adapter-for-an-ethernet-ready-tv-new-version/

Comment: Here's an [article](http://blog.ithasu.org/2016/10/using-a-raspberry-pi-3-as-a-wifi-access-point-and-bridge/) describing exactly what you'd like to do. I'm not sure why Dmitry Grigoryev seems to think else wise. I've currently got a pi3 in the ceiling of my office bridged to a switch and distributing wired internet all over my office. It's just linking two interfaces. The only frustrating part is that I do have to assign a static IP to the the Ethernet port on the pi.

Comment: Check out [this guide](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=204361). <BR/>There seems to be a solution, with help of OpenVPN.

Answer (score 9):

This is not currently possible. Wireless bridges require 802.11 frames to store 4 addresses (sender, receiver, destination and source), and standard 802.11 frames only store 3 addresses. While there are implementations of 4-address mode called [WDS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_distribution_system), they are [vendor-specific](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/clientmode) and only supported on router hardware (meaning you should use hardware from the same vendor for this to work). On routers, the [command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155041/bridging-loosing-wlan-network-connection-with-4addr-on-option-why) to enable WDS (and allow bridging of Wlan interfaces) mode is

```
iw dev wlan0 set 4addr on
```

You can try it, but AFAIK it won't work on the RPi 3, at least not with built-in NIC. You may have some luck with USB adapters based on Atheros wireless chipsets. Until it does, you'll have to stick to NAT if you want to connect networks via RPi, as described [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13440/bridge-wifi-and-ethernet). You can also try [Wlan kabel](https://github.com/escitalopram/wlan_kabel), but that's not real bridging either.

PS. I know the negative answer is not that useful, but we have lots of duplicate questions about bridging, and they can't be closed properly unless one of them is answered.

Answer (score 3):

So as not to confuse readers :-
Dmitry Grigoryev is correct he stated you need WDS and you do to create the infrastructure shown above.

Do not confuse Ethernet:wifi -> Wifi:Ethernet with wifi:ethernet - > ethernet:wifi

One just requires a Bridge between the access Point and Lan the other requires WDS to control the link.

As above, the article mentioned covers a wireless Access Point not Wireless Distribution System (WDS)