# Transparrently bridge eth0 to wlan0

Tags: raspbian, networking

I have a device connected to eth0 that should behave like connected directly to the network that wlan0 is connected to.
How can I achive this?

**I do not want to use NAT on eth0**, since this would defeat the purpose because devices on the wlan0 network could not see the device connected to eth0.

Comment: this is actually not RPi related .... you want to use `linux as a switch`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Raspberry PI 3 MODEL B - Wireless Bridge to ethernet](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51057/raspberry-pi-3-model-b-wireless-bridge-to-ethernet)