# Is it possible to make a WIFI to LAN Bridge with the RaspberryPi3b and Bridge Utils?

Tags: pi-3, wifi, ethernet-port, bridge

I am currently trying to make a bridge between the Wifi and Lan on the Raspberry Pi 3b with Raspberry Pi Os Lite for an Assignment. The Task is to connect the Raspberry to the Wifi and then Bridge it to the Lan Port. The Raspberry can't work as an Accespoint and has to be connected to an existing Wifi Network. It should than work as a Bridge between an existing Wifi and the LAN Port of the Pi. I have now been looking around for quite some time but have only been able to find [this article](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/88954/workaround-for-a-wifi-bridge-on-a-raspberry-pi-with-proxy-arp/88955#88955) which says it isn't possible with the inbuilt Wifi Chip on the Raspberry. The Professor who gave this Tasks says that it is possible to do it with [Bridge Utils](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/bridge-utils), the problem is, that i haven't found any explaination on how to do it. Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Please, a sentence is started with capital letter and I is also capital i !

Comment: Could you get away with running the Pi as the WiFi access point or does the Pi have to connect to an existing WiFi network and act as the bridge?  Please edit your question and explain a bit more about the way you see the Pi working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a Raspberry Pi you will never find an explanation how you can bridge a wired interface with a WiFi interface used for a client connection to another hotspot. Also **Bridge Utils** cannot do it. Please tell it to your Professor. If he is able to do it please ask him to publish it as fast as possible. We are missing this feature since years. For now you have to use routing. For some more details you can look at [Raspberry Pi WiFi to Ethernet Bridge](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/81518/79866) and [Wireless Bridge to ethernet](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/55731/79866).

Comment: Yes - I wanted to do this recently, but gave up on RPi as a solution. Instead, I pressed an old-ish [GL-AR150](https://store.gl-inet.com/collections/all-wifi-devices/products/gl-ar150-mini-smart-router) into service. It was very easy to set up - still amazed at just how easy with the new OpenWRT firmware.